# Error 404 There isn't a GitHub Pages site here

Tags: github-pages, cloudflare, cname

I'm trying to load my site at custom domain. But it's not working.
It seems to me that I Checked everything and it's still not working. I used this short tutorial (https://medium.freecodecamp.com/domain-registrars-dns-and-hosting-353e4163a19#.wdqj4056m).
This is what I'm getting in bash using dig:

```
taras@t626:~$ dig parkan.trade +nostats +nocomments +nocmd
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.8-Ubuntu <<>> parkan.trade +nostats +nocomments +nocmd<br/>
;; global options: +cmd
;parkan.trade.                  IN  A
parkan.trade.          45       IN  A       104.28.8.106
parkan.trade.          45       IN  A       104.28.9.106
parkan.trade.           6945    IN  NS      SKIP.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM.
parkan.trade.           6945    IN  NS      TRICIA.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM.
SKIP.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM. 26515   IN  A       173.245.59.233
SKIP.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM. 171614  IN  AAAA    2400:cb00:2049:1::adf5:3be9
TRICIA.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM. 32805 IN  A       173.245.58.232
TRICIA.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM. 42485 IN  AAAA    2400:cb00:2049:1::adf5:3ae8
```

This is my settings in cloudflare:
[image]

The webpage from  working properly http://y-taras.github.io/

Comment: forgot to mention that I've added the CNAME file to repository with a <username.github.io> text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CNAME` file must contain `parkan.trade` and not `y-taras.github.io`